# Using variables in Sourcedata

Tags: excel, vba

How can i do this code works right, I need to use a variable

`Act = InputBox("Today", "Now", Thisday)`

Here i need to write: 10513 (sheet name).

`Range("AA2").Select`

This works OK

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
SourceData:="'10513'!R1C23:R117C23").CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="'[Control LE.xls]10513'!R4C27", _
TableName:="Tabla dinámica3", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion10
```

This doesn't...

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
SourceData:="' Act '!R1C23:R117C23").CreatePivotTable _
TableDestination:="'[Control LE.xls]& Act '!R4C27", TableName:="Tabla dinámica3", _
DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion10
```

Comment: Have you had a chance to try my suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You're simply passing in the string `Act` as the worksheet name. To send this name (stored in a string variable, use string concatenation technique, note the differences below:

```
Debug.Print "' Act '"
```

vs.

```
Debug.Print "'" & Act & "'"
```

Applying this to your snippet of code, this should work:

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:="'" & Act & "'!R1C23:R117C23").CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="'[Control LE.xls]& Act '!R4C27", TableName:="Tabla dinámica3", _
    DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion10
```